# Silverlight 5.0 not being recognized as installed

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I have moved some of my projects to a new computer Windows 8.1 with the same version of Visual Studios 2010. When I try to open the solution it says install the latest Silverlight Runtime version and I did and then restarted the computer. When I try to run the solution again it has the same error. How do I fix this?

What is shown on computer:

```
Microsoft Silverlight
Microsoft Silverlight 3.0 SDK
Microsoft Silverlight 4.0 SDK
Microsoft Silverlight 5.0 SDK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reapply my Visual Studios 2010 SP1 - it did a rollback. Now the solution opens. Hope this is helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this [addons/pre-requisites download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28358) installed?  I'm pretty sure Silverlight 5 came out after VS2010, so I think at least something needs to be done (looks to be included in linked download) to patch VS2010 so it supports Silverlight 5 development.

Comment: Thanks, but that is the exact one I installed.